# Android: TextView having text of more than one line is not clickable/long clickable

Tags: android, textview

When TextView containing chat message is having content more than accommodatable in one line, the text view stops listening for clicks and long clicks. I tried to listen same events on the parent item of TextView, but it's not working there as well.
This is the code:

```
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/message_text_view"
                        android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:longClickable="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
                        android:paddingStart="20sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="20sp"
                        android:text="@string/hello"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Java code:

```
messageRightBinding.messageTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    messageRightBinding.messageTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

**Full XML layout file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conversation_time"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="20sp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="2 July, 2018"
            android:textColor="@color/light_black"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:longClickable="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/message_holder">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/message_text_view"
                        android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"
                        android:clickable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:longClickable="false"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="8sp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
                        android:paddingStart="20sp"
                        android:paddingEnd="20sp"
                        android:text="@string/hello"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/message_button_holder"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <Button
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_whitebackground"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_pink"
                        android:id="@+id/unsend_button_right"
                        android:layout_width="90sp"
                        android:layout_height="40sp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                        android:padding="6sp"
                        android:text="@string/unsend" />
                    <Button
                        android:background="@drawable/rounded_whitebackground"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_pink"
                        android:id="@+id/unsend_button_right_hide"
                        android:layout_width="30sp"
                        android:layout_height="40sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:padding="8sp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                        android:text="@string/x" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:longClickable="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                    android:text="@string/_11_00pm"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_black"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
                <ImageView
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:id="@+id/indicator_image_view"
                    android:layout_margin="2sp"
                    android:layout_width="12sp"
                    android:layout_height="12sp"
                    android:tint="@color/light_black"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**Full RecyclerView code**

```
package batteries;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.util.DiffUtil;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.R;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.databinding.MessageLeftBinding;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.databinding.MessageRightBinding;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.db.AppDatabase;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.db.Contacts;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.db.DatabaseInstance;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.db.NewMessage;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.fragment.ChatFragment2;
import com.titanictek.titanicapp.services.WebSocketTypes;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public class ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

    Context context;
    private UUID userId;

    // private String threadId;

    private Contacts contact;
    private ArrayList<NewMessage> newMessages;

    private static final int MESSAGE_SENT = 1;
    private static final int MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 2;
    final private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    final ChatFragment2.OnSeenCallback onSeen;

    public ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2(Context context, UUID userId, String threadId, Contacts contact, RecyclerView recyclerView, ChatFragment2.OnSeenCallback onSeen) {
        this.context = context;
        this.userId = userId;
        // this.threadId = threadId;
        this.contact = contact;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
        this.newMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        this.onSeen = onSeen;
    }

    public void setContact(Contacts contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public void addMessagesFirst(List<NewMessage> messages) {
        newMessages.addAll(0, messages);
        // recyclerView.getLayoutManager().fi

        notifyDataSetChanged();

        recyclerView.scrollToPosition(messages.size()+5);
    }

    // todo: Add SCROLL logic
    public void clearMessages() {
        newMessages.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        scrollToBottom();
    }

    public void addMessagesInLast(List<NewMessage> messages) {
        newMessages.addAll(messages);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        scrollToBottom();
    }

    public void addMessage(NewMessage message) {
        newMessages.add(message);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        scrollToBottom();
    }

    public void onMessageSeen(ArrayList<String> messageIds) {
        int c = messageIds.size();
        for (NewMessage message: newMessages) {
            if (messageIds.contains(message.getMessageId())) {
                message.setReached(3);
                c--;
                if (c==0) break;
            }
        }

        if (c < messageIds.size()) notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void onMessageSent(WebSocketTypes.ChatMessageDeliveryStatus status) {
        for (NewMessage message: newMessages) {
            if (message.getMessageId().equals(status.refId.toString())) {
                message.setReached(1);
                message.setMessageId(status.messageId.toString());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onMessageDelivered(String messageId) {
        for (NewMessage message: newMessages) {
            if (message.getMessageId().equals(messageId)) {
                message.setReached(2);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addMessagesInLast(NewMessage ...messages) {
        final int oldSize = newMessages.size();
        newMessages.addAll(Arrays.asList(messages));
        // notifyDataSetChanged();

        DiffUtil.DiffResult diffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(new DiffUtil.Callback() {

            @Override
            public int getOldListSize() {
                return oldSize;
            }

            @Override
            public int getNewListSize() {
                return newMessages.size();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return newItemPosition < oldSize;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
                return newItemPosition < oldSize;
            }
        });
        diffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(this);
        scrollToBottom();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == MESSAGE_SENT){
            return new SendMessageHolder(MessageRightBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
            );
        } else {
            return new ReceiveMessageHolder(MessageLeftBinding.inflate(
                    LayoutInflater.from(context), parent, false)
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        NewMessage message = newMessages.get(position);
        if(message.getUserId().equals(userId.toString())){
            ((SendMessageHolder) holder).bind(message, position);
        } else {
            if (!message.isSeen()) {
                message.setReached(3);
                onSeen.run(message);
            }
            ((ReceiveMessageHolder) holder).bind(message, position);
        }
    }

    public void scrollToBottom() {
        if (getItemCount() > 0) {
            Log.w("SCROLL", "DONE");
            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(getItemCount());
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        NewMessage newMessage = newMessages.get(position);
        if (newMessage.getUserId().equals(userId.toString())) {
            return MESSAGE_SENT;
        } else {
            return MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    private int getItemViewType(NewMessage newMessage) {
        //Log.w("NewMessage SentBy", newMessage.getUserId());
        //Log.w("NewMessage Received By", contacts.getId());
        if (newMessage.getUserId().equals(userId.toString())) {
            return MESSAGE_SENT;
        } else {
            return MESSAGE_RECEIVED;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newMessages.size();
    }

    private class SendMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private MessageRightBinding messageRightBinding;

        SendMessageHolder(MessageRightBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.messageRightBinding = binding;
        }

        public void bind(NewMessage newMessage, int position){
//            messageRightBinding.mes.setText(newMessage.getText());
            messageRightBinding.messageTextView.setText(newMessage.getText());
            /*Picasso.rest().load(contacts.getProfilePicture()).resize(50, 50).
                    into(messageRightBinding.messageRightPp);*/
            if (newMessage.isSeen()) {
                messageRightBinding.indicatorImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_eye_black_24dp));
            } else {
                if (newMessage.isSent())
                    messageRightBinding.indicatorImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_check_black_24dp));
                else //  if (newMessage.isSentFailed())
                    messageRightBinding.indicatorImageView.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_access_time_black_24dp));
            }
            messageRightBinding.timeTextView.setText(ContentUtils.getTime(newMessage.getTime()));

            long lastTime = 0;
            messageRightBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (position != 0) {
                lastTime = ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2.this.newMessages.get(position - 1).getTime();
                if (newMessage.getTime() - lastTime >= 20000000) {
                    messageRightBinding.conversationTime.setText(new Date(newMessage.getTime()).toString());
                    messageRightBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                messageRightBinding.conversationTime.setText(new Date(newMessage.getTime()).toString());
                messageRightBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            messageRightBinding.messageButtonHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            messageRightBinding.messageHolder.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    messageRightBinding.messageButtonHolder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            messageRightBinding.unsendButtonRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    messageRightBinding.unsendButtonRight.removeCallbacks(null);
                    // newMessages.remove(position);
                    newMessages.remove(position);
                    notifyDataSetChanged(); // position -1, newMessages.size() - position );
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unsending the message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            messageRightBinding.unsendButtonRightHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    messageRightBinding.messageButtonHolder.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });

        }
    }

    private class ReceiveMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private MessageLeftBinding messageLeftBinding;

        ReceiveMessageHolder(MessageLeftBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.messageLeftBinding = binding;
        }

        public void bind(NewMessage newMessage, int position){
            messageLeftBinding.messageTextView.setText(newMessage.getText());

            if (position +1 < ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2.this.getItemCount() && contact != null)
                if (ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2.this.getItemViewType(position+1) != MESSAGE_RECEIVED)
                {

                    Picasso.get().load(contact.getProfilePicture()).resize(50, 50).
                            into(messageLeftBinding.messageLeftPp);
                    messageLeftBinding.messageLeftPp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                    messageLeftBinding.messageLeftPp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else if(contact != null)  {
                Picasso.get().load(contact.getProfilePicture()).resize(50, 50).
                        into(messageLeftBinding.messageLeftPp);
                messageLeftBinding.messageLeftPp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            long lastTime = 0;
            messageLeftBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (position != 0) {
                lastTime = ChatMessageRecyclerAdapter2.this.newMessages.get(position - 1).getTime();
                if (newMessage.getTime() - lastTime >= 20000000) {
                    messageLeftBinding.conversationTime.setText(new Date(newMessage.getTime()).toString());
                    messageLeftBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            } else {
                messageLeftBinding.conversationTime.setText(new Date(newMessage.getTime()).toString());
                messageLeftBinding.conversationTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            messageLeftBinding.timeTextView.setText(ContentUtils.getTime(newMessage.getTime()));
        }
    }
}
```

Screenshot:
Here the Unsend and X button come on long click, but that works only for one liner messages.
[image]

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated and I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

try putting your text in a relativelayout and give the click listener to the relative layout

Comment: any reasons behind doing so?

Comment: try it and let me know if it works and give the relative layout a background color to make sure it is being clicked

Comment: Did you even try this solution before putting here? Sorry It's not working

Comment: sure man hmm 
so you must think this way that is something blocking your click 
good luck

Comment: In a way your solution is right. that wrapping in RelativeLayout...onclicklistener is not a concern.

Comment: yea there is no problem with your click listener
so can i get an upvote :D

Comment: Upvotes on this community are not the person dear, it's to the answer. But still +1 to welcome you into the community.

Answer (score 0):

Set `android:clickable="true"` and `android:longClickable="true"` on your `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SendMessageHolder` class, replace

```
messageRightBinding.messageHolder.setOnLongClickListener
```

with

```
itemView.setOnLongClickListener
```

You shouldn't set a long-click listener on a child View in a RecyclerView.

Comment: Please read the message on top of screenshot. It's working when message length is one line, but when it outflows of the first line it doesn't work.

So I doubt this "You can't set a long-click listener on a child View in a RecyclerView.".

Comment: @RavinderPayal I did read that. When you do stuff in Android that you shouldn't, it might work in some cases, but it usually won't.

Comment: OK that's weird. I don't know on my part or Android part. Let me try that as well.

Comment: @RavinderPayal you have a point though. I've changed it to say "shouldn't" instead.

Comment: Tested with multi liner as well it's working as expected.

"You shouldn't set a long-click listener on a child View in a RecyclerView." this thing is yet to be validated, and I still doubt. Please add any supporting documentation or article.

Comment: Yes on removing everything but TextView from layout

Comment: So it only works if you remove everything but the TextView? @RavinderPayal

Comment: till now yes, I am adding things again...let me tell you the actual cause.

Comment: If it stops working again, make sure that the TextView is _not_ long-clickable, and in your `bind()` method, add `itemView.setLongClickable(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone for wasting your time and frying your heads for a problem which was not there actually. Those two buttons "Unsend" and "X" were not visible because when the TextView got content in length more than a line, it's was using the full width of screen leaving no space for other things. Hence even when the button's state was visible the buttons were not there in view port. Causing this so lengthy discussion and a misleading question title.

Finally this worked for me:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:padding="4dp">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/message_holder"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:longClickable="true">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message_text_view"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble_right"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
        android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="8sp"
        android:paddingBottom="8sp"
        android:paddingStart="20sp"
        android:paddingEnd="20sp"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/message_button_holder"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/message_button_holder"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_whitebackground"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_pink"
            android:id="@+id/unsend_button_right"
            android:layout_width="90sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:padding="6sp"
            android:text="@string/unsend" />
        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_whitebackground"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/dark_pink"
            android:id="@+id/unsend_button_right_hide"
            android:layout_width="30sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:padding="8sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
            android:text="@string/x" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Sorry to everyone once again.